# Why is it said, that GEE is not likelihood based, IF the estimating equations are derived exactly thru d(log(L)/dB?

Tags: mixed-model, maximum-likelihood, generalized-estimating-equations

I found this article: https://sakai.unc.edu/access/content/group/2842013b-58f5-4453-aa8d-3e01bacbfc3d/public/Ecol562_Spring2012/docs/lectures/lecture22.htm#choosing
and most of it is showing the origin of estimating equations, going exactly through the ML estimation.

Then it's switched to "quasi-likelihood" and said, that:

> "The connection between quasi-likelihood and likelihood theory is
> actually quite close. It turns out that GEE estimates have the same
> large sample properties that MLEs do—they're consistent,
> asymptotically normal, etc. In addition, the quasi-likelihood can be
> used to generate an AIC-like quantity for use in model selection."

So why do all textbooks I read and teachers that I asked say, that GEE is not likelihood-based?

As a consequence - the deviance cannot be calculated, so no LR testing for the main and interaction effects can be done and it needs to employ the Wald's approximations.